# NoReverseMatch exception while using ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES

Tags: django

I have an account app which handles user login,logout, registration , password change etc. I have made a Custom profile model by extending the Django.auth's User model.
I have 2 additional views to list the active users(user_list) and detail of active user(user_detail) rendered as template after the user logs in. Since every user must have a canonical URL so I am using ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES setting which is as follows:

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: reverse_lazy('user_detail',
                                   args=[u.username]),
}
```

So now when I use {{ user.get_absolute_url }} in the list.html template to redirect to template that renders the user_detail view,I get an error :

"Reverse for 'user_detail' with arguments '('ujjawal2295',)' and keyword        arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/users/(?P[-  w]+)/$']"

Comment: Please post your url patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong regex.

```
['account/users/(?P[- w]+)/$']
```

Instead of this.

```
['account/users/(?P[-\w]+)/$']
```

You missed the backslash “\”.

Use this tool in the future http://pythex.org/

Comment: Oh that was so foolish of me. Thanks anyway.